# How to export Mongodb data to Mysql every one hour time automatically?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

> mongoexport --db dbname --collection collname --type=csv --fields _id,name -query {$lastUpdated:{$lte : }} --out filepath

Comment: I tried this one :    mongoexport --db dbname --collection collname --type=csv --fields _id,name --query '{lastUpdated : {$lte : "timestamp-60*60*1000" }}' --out filepath

Comment: try to use cron

Comment: Improved the title.

Answer (score 0):

> created a shellscript :                                                  v1=`date +%s`
>   v2=1000
>   v3=`expr $v1 \* $v2`
>   v4=`expr 60 \* 60 \* 1000`
>   v5=`expr $v3 - $v4`

mongoexport --db dbname --collection collname --type=csv --fields _id,name --query '{lastUpdated : { $gte :NumberLong("'$v5'")  }}' --out filepath ;       ////Working perfect :)

Comment: If this works for you, please remember to "accept" it, so SO can properly archive the question.